# How to use .csv file with xyz coordinates(RD_NEW) and implement in Unity?

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I'm working on a personal project in which I want to visualize airplanes above airports. I created a .csv file containing the coordinates of one airplane over a certain period of time. I tried to write a code in Unity in which the coordinates are linked to a cube and moves over time. Unfortunately my code does not work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO

public class AirplanePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject airplane;
    public TextAsset csvFile;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
    }


    void readCSV()
    {
        string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
        for(int i = 0; i < records; i++)
        {airplane.transform.position(float.Parse(fields[2]),float.Parse(fields[3]),  float.Parse(fields[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results would be a cube which moves in different directions over time. Would love some tips, thank you in advance!

Comment: Your program does not know what `fields` is. Declare it. `readCSV` is never called. You probably need to learn about how [Unity event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventFunctions.html) work. Don't call `position(...);`, assign a `Vector3` to it: `position = new Vector3(x, y, z);`. Don't compare an int to an array, but to the `Length` of it.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: if you want your airplane to move over time, you wouldnt read the csv and then just say be at each spot as it will pretty much happen in one frame.. you need to spread them out

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My code does not compile. I will try to read the Unity event functions. Could you maybe give me an example of how you think the code would work?

Comment: Why would you not just use transforms in the editor and move to them? Reading in data seems like an added level of complexity.

Comment: I am pretty often amazed that developers insist on parsing CSV files themselves rather than using a library. Sure it's quick and easy to open a text file, read lines, and split on commas, so long as the CSV file is small, doesn't contain embedded commas, or some other CSV gotcha. Something like this is very easy to use and covers all of the common gotchas: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GenericParsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To move the plane between points you could use the [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) method.
  Here is a very basic implementation of what I understand you are trying to accomplish:

  ```
  public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public TextAsset coordinates;
      public int moveSpeed;

      string[] coordinatesArray;
      int currentPointIndex = 0;
      Vector3 destinationVector;

      void Start()
      {
          coordinatesArray = coordinates.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
      }

      void Update()
      {
          if (destinationVector == null || transform.position == destinationVector)
          {
              currentPointIndex = currentPointIndex < coordinatesArray.Length - 1 ? currentPointIndex + 1 : 1;
              if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(coordinatesArray[currentPointIndex]))
              {
                  string[] xyz = coordinatesArray[currentPointIndex].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                  destinationVector = new Vector3(float.Parse(xyz[0]), float.Parse(xyz[1]), float.Parse(xyz[1]));
              }
          }
          else
          {
              transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, destinationVector, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  [image]
- I also made it do a little loop with the coordinates and added a speed property.
- I'm not really sure if adding the csv file as public TextAsset for the game object is the right approach, maybe it makes more sense to use the file **path** for the csv file instead and get the file data from code.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. My plane controller is not reading the Coordinates. The yellow part you highlighted is missing the Coordinates option and Move Speed?

Comment: The error: Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: My "coordinates" field is your "csvFile" field, its just a different naming convention. I assumed you populated your csvFile field by dragging and dropping the csv file over it. You dont really need the moveSpeed field, you can just use a static value in the MoveTowards method call.

Comment: Fixed! Now it says input string is not in correct format?

Comment: Are you using VisualStudio to code? If so, use the debugger to find out where it gives you this error and why. Here is a small [video about debugging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3kqIlLzIig).

Comment: I updated the code so it shouldn't give off any more errors in the console, but I strongly advise you to look into debugging, this will save you loads of time and stress and it also helps you understand how the code works.

Comment: Thanks for the information and advice. Still receive the error: input string is not in correct format. Think it has something to do with my csv file?

Comment: -925.9236290065019,12351.97445070598,571.5
 -966.3328531926963,11629.066903930157,533.4
 -1046.392145349062,10272.26557199203,472.44
 -1060.4963215185562,10216.754913891666,464.82

Comment: Might be your csv data, try doing some tests first with simpler values like only 2 rows of data [2,3,2],[1,2,1] and go from there. You won't really know where that error is coming from until you use the debugger to identify it. Its also a good practice to split the code up when you have a bug that you cant crack (instead of composing the destination vector on one line, split the code up in multiple lines, like extracting the x,y,z float values in variables and then composing the vector out of them)